# Find and replace in big files with Objective C, counting the number of replacements

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, macos

I need to perform a find and replace (with regular expression) within a file using objective C.

My current solution is like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:sourceFile encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[toFind stringValue] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:[toReplace stringValue]];
[modifiedString writeToFile:sourceFile atomically:YES]
```

There are 2 problems with this solution:

1 - I can't get the number of occurrences replaced

2 - I think this is not really fast when loading files of nearly 300MB, because i'm loading the entire file into memory as a string.

How can i get the count of replacements made, and optimise my solution to have good performances even with big files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solution: Don't use `NSRegularExpression`, find a good C library. There are much better solutions out there, and, for the love of god, use `mmap` instead of reading the entire file into a `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfMatchesInString` called before you replace the matches will let you know how many times an occurrence will be replaced. Instead of loading the entire file into memory, do it piecemeal and keep a counter that you add the results of `numberOfMatchesInString` to.